# eval json data get different length in IE and firefox

Tags: javascript, json

I got json data from the server by ajax:

```
request.responseText=[{name:xxx},{name:xxx},{name:xx}].
```

Then I use the

```
var data=eval(request.responseText);

alert(data.length);
```

In IE,it is "4",while in Firefox it is "3".

Use the IE debugger I found that the element in data is like:

```
[Methods]
[0]
[1]
[2]
```

So itis length is 4.

I wonder why?

Comment: What is the **exact** string?

Comment: data from the server:[{name:“kk”,age:30,id:0},{ name:“kddk”,age:20,id:1 }{ name:“kkdd”,age:330,id:3 }]

Comment: hguser: that data has a syntax error in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the server returned data with a trailing comma, for example:

```
[1, 2, 3, ]
```

In IE, this array will be interpreted as having a length 4, while in standard compliant browsers, it will have a length 3.

Answer (score 0):

`[Methods]` is a separate node shown by the debugger to separate functions from other values.
It does not actually exist in the object.

If an array has three items named `0`, `1`, and `2`, its `length` **will** be `3`.

Comment: but,when I alert it,it'svalue is 4